# Spring AOP not working on downstream methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using spring AOP to log performance times of both the entire transaction and sub transactions for an endpoint defined with @RequestMapping.

I have an endpoint defined like this:

```
package com.example.service

@RestController
public class endpoints {    

    @Autowired
    SomeObject object;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/123", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public void test() {
        object.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**My example object**

```
    package com.example.objects

    @Repository
    public class SomeObject { 

        public void doSomething() {
             System.out.println("doing something");
       }
   }
```

**Logging aspect:**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

     // THIS WORKS
     @Around(value = "within(com.example.service                                                          ..*) && @annotation(mapping) ")
public Object logEndpoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequestMapping mapping) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Endpoint works!!");
}

     // THIS DOES NOT WORK
     @Around("execution(*  com.example.objects.SomeObject.doSomething(..))")
    public void specificMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("LOGGING FOR REALS YA'LL");
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

When I deploy this and I hit the endpoint applicationName/123, the logging works just fine for the endpoint.  The problem is that I do not get my logging for "doSomething()".  I thought that autowiring would create the appropriate proxy that I needed for the aspect to work but apparently it does not.  How can i appropriately call my method "doSomething()" to get it to log with the aspect?

Comment: You don't have an import for com.example.objects.SomeObject & call for joinPoint.proceed(), I suppose this is a typo? Have you tried with a Pointcut
@Pointcut("com.example.objects.SomeObject.doSomething()")?

Comment: yes, thats a typo. Yes i have tried with a pointcut as well.  It is essentially the same thing from what i have read.  It just separates the declaration of "exection(...)" from the @Around declaration and makes it easier to organize.  I am simply trying to get to work first and refactor later.

Comment: does within(com.example.objects..*) work ?

Comment: It might be that SomeObj is already a proxy of a kind, so it does not respond to com.example.objects.SomeObject, and for Spring this is already a proxy bean. Can you define an interface that this SomeObj implements, and use it as a reference in your aspect, or use some annotation on doSomething.

Comment: I found my issue.  The above example is actually working code.  I wrote it to try and illustrate my issue, but i did not do that accurately.  What i was doing was calling a local method and trying to use AOP on that, but it does not work that way.  The autowire does take care of what i expected it to.  Thanks to those who helped, it got me on the right track to solve my  issue.